# Django - command createsuperuser creates superuser in the default database when passing the --database parameter

Tags: django

I have three Postgre databases in my project:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'default',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    },
    'clients_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'clients_db',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    },
    'other': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'other',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    },
}
```

And three apps: **clients**, **users** and **myapp**.

The app **clients** have a router for the *clients_db* database:

```
class ClientsRouter:

    route_app_labels = {'clients'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'clients_db'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'clients_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'clients_db'
        return None
```

The other two apps uses the same database. I can run migrations and migrate just fine using the commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then, to apply migrations to the *default* database:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

And to apply migrations to the *other* database:

```
python manage.py migrate --database other
```

But when I try to run the command to create a superuser in the *other* database, it creates a superuser in the *default* database instead. The command:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser --database other
```

The installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'clients',
    'users',
    'myapp',
    'django_filters',
    'widget_tweaks',
]
```

From what I understand based on the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser) the command should work and create the superuser in the specified database. Any ideas what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

Following the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#using-managers-with-multiple-databases), I tried to create the superuser using shell, but even specifying the database like the instructions in the link, it still creates in the *default* database.

Comment: They mentioned in the docs that the superuser will be installed in the database which has django auth system installed on it.. I think in this case is the default database

Comment: The docs say that "the command is only available if Django’s authentication system (django.contrib.auth) is installed". The app is installed and is listed in the apps list. When i run the "migrate --database other" command, it installs the system in this database (creates the tables for the users, auth etc.).

Comment: In the shell started with `manage.py shell`, what does `User._default_manager.db_manager('other')._db` return?

Comment: It returns 'other'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been some time, but since there where no other replies, I'm posting how I got around the problem posted in the question: I used shell to copy the user from the *default* database to the *other* database using these commands:

```
python manage.py shell

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
Users = get_user_model()
u = Users.objects.get(pk=1)
u.save(using='other')
```

The second and third lines are needed because I use a custom user model. If the standard user model is used, the commands are:

```
python manage.py shell

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
u = Users.objects.get(pk=1)
u.save(using='other')
```

Lastly, I have a multi-tenancy middleware that uses threading and I thought it was causing the issue described in the question, but for me it's weird that even using shell this happens. Anyway, this is how i solved it.